# How can this Invoice Soap XmlValidation java code be in C#?

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, soap

**I want to make a C# soap invoice signing/verification console app.**

I don't have experience with soap neither in c# nor java.

The only working code i have been able to find is this (in java).

I want to use the same method but in C#.

*How can i convert it to C# to fit my needs?*

***What would the code below be in C#?***

---

```
     import java.io.*;
        import java.security.cert.*;
        import java.util.*;
        import javax.xml.crypto.*;
        import javax.xml.crypto.dom.*;
        import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.*;
        import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.*;
        import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.*;
        import javax.xml.parsers.*;
        import org.w3c.dom.*;
        import org.xml.sax.*;
        public class SampleValidateSignature
        {private static final XMLSignatureFactory xmlSigFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
    private static final String RESPONSE_TO_VALIDATE =
"<env:Envelope xmlns:env=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n" +
" <env:Header/>\r\n" +
" <env:Body>\r\n" +
" <RegisterInvoiceResponse " +
" xmlns=\"https://192.168.1.111/ePayService/schema\" " +
" xmlns:ns0=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\" " +
" Id=\"Response\" " +
" Version=\"3\">\r\n" +
" <Header>...</Header>\r\n" +
" <FIC>...</FIC>\r\n" +
" <Signature>..</Signature>\r\n" +
" </RegisterInvoiceResponse>\r\n" +
" </env:Body>\r\n" +
"</env:Envelope>";


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
            {
                // Get DOC from String XML
                DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(RESPONSE_TO_VALIDATE)));
            // Get signature node
            NodeList signatureNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, XML_SIGNATURE_ELEMENT);
if (signatureNodeList.getLength() == 0) {
throw new Exception(String.format("XML signature element %s not found.", XML_SIGNATURE_ELEMENT));
}
        Node signatureNode = signatureNodeList.item(0);
        // Get signature element
        DOMStructure ds = new DOMStructure(signatureNode);
        XMLSignature signature;
try {
signature = xmlSigFactory.unmarshalXMLSignature(ds);
} catch (MarshalException e) {
throw new Exception("Signature extraction exception.", e);
}
// Get certificate from signature element
X509Certificate cert;
KeyInfo keyInfo = signature.getKeyInfo();
if (keyInfo == null)
{
    throw new Exception("KeyInfo element is missing.");
}
else
{
    List <?> list = keyInfo.getContent();
    if (list.size() != 1)
    {
        throw new Exception("More than one KeyInfo element.");
    }
    else
    {
        Object info = list.get(0);
        if (!(info instanceof X509Data)) {
            throw new Exception("KeyInfo element is not x509 certificate.");
        }
        SignatureMethod sm = signature.getSignedInfo().getSignatureMethod();
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)((X509Data)info).getContent().get(0);
        if (!sm.getAlgorithm().equalsIgnoreCase(XML_SIG_METHOD) ||
        !certificate.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm().equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_ALGORITHM))
        {
            throw new Exception("Valid certificate not found.");
        }
        cert = certificate;
    }
}
// Get response node
NodeList responseNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XML_SCHEMA_NS, XML_RESPONSE_ELEMENT);
if (responseNodeList.getLength() == 0)
{
    throw new Exception(String.format("XML element %s not found.", XML_RESPONSE_ELEMENT));
}
Node responseNode = responseNodeList.item(0);
DOMValidateContext dvc = new DOMValidateContext(cert.getPublicKey(), signatureNode);
dvc.setIdAttributeNS((Element)responseNode, null, "Id");
// Get signedInfo element
SignedInfo signedInfo = signature.getSignedInfo();
List <?> refList = signedInfo.getReferences();
if (refList != null && refList.size() != 1)
{
    throw new Exception(String.format("Only one signature reference allowed, provided %s.", refList.size()));
}
// Check methods
Reference reference = (Reference)refList.get(0);
if (reference.getURI() == null || !reference.getURI().equals("#" + XML_RESPONSE_ID))
{
    throw new Exception(String.format("Signature reference URI must be provided with value \"%s\".", XML_RESPONSE_ID));
}
if (!signedInfo.getSignatureMethod().getAlgorithm().equalsIgnoreCase(XML_SIG_METHOD))
{
    throw new Exception(String.format("Signature method should be %s, provided %s.", XML_SIG_METHOD,
    signedInfo.getSignatureMethod().getAlgorithm()));
}
if (!signedInfo.getCanonicalizationMethod().getAlgorithm().equalsIgnoreCase(CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE))
{
    throw new Exception(String.format("Canonicalization method should be %s, provided %s.", CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE,
    signedInfo.getCanonicalizationMethod().getAlgorithm()));
}
if (!reference.getDigestMethod().getAlgorithm().equalsIgnoreCase(DigestMethod.SHA256))
{
    throw new Exception(String.format("Digest method should be %s, provided %s.", DigestMethod.SHA256,
    reference.getDigestMethod().getAlgorithm()));
}
// Validate signature value
try
{
    boolean isValid = signature.validate(dvc);
    if (!isValid)
    {
        boolean signatureValueStatus = signature.getSignatureValue().validate(dvc);
        if (!signatureValueStatus)
        {
            throw new Exception("Validation failed with signature value wrong.");
        }
        boolean referenceStatus = reference.validate(dvc);
        if (!referenceStatus)
        {
            throw new Exception("Validation failed with digest wrong.");
        }
    }
}
catch (XMLSignatureException e)
{
    throw new Exception("Signature validation failed.", e);
}
// Do additional checks
// * Check that certificate is issued by Admin CA
// * Check that CN of the certificate contains value "Invoicer ePay"
// Conclusion
System.out.println("Signature is valid");
}}}}
```

Comment: Use a Java to C# converter or go through the code line by line changing the syntax from Java to C#.

Comment: I did it but it is not working for me. I tried many online java to c# converters.